# Load nib views into UIScrollView using SnapKit programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, snapkit

I need to load nib files into scroll view programmatically and need to pin constraints to scroll view. My views are complex so I decided to go with Nib but have to add them programmatically in scroll view. I tried almost all the methods but constraints dont seem to be working. Please see my code below.

1) create scroll view and add constraints:

```
scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.edges.equalTo(view)
    make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

2) add content view into scroll view:

```
contentView = UIView()
contentView.backgroundColor = .red
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.edges.equalTo(scrollView)
    make.size.height.equalTo(scrollView)
    make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

3) load the Nib view and add them in content view. Trick here is to set the first view width to scroll view so it automatically resize to each view size and make all child views equal width:

```
var previous: customView =  customView()
// suppose we have three custom views need to loaded from Nib and add in scroll view 
for i in 0..<3 {
    let view = customView() // Tried giving frame as well but no success
    view.initWithTitle(tutorailArray![i].heading, title: tutorailArray![i].title, image: tutorailArray![i].imageName)
    self.contentView.addSubview(view)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.snp.makeConstraints({ [weak contentView, previous, scrollView] (make) in

       make.top.bottom.equalTo(contentView!)

        if ( i == 0) {
            make.size.width.equalTo(scrollView)
            make.leading.equalTo(contentView!)
        }
        else {
            make.size.width.equalTo(previous)
            make.leading.equalTo(previous)
        }

        if i == 2 {
            make.size.width.equalTo(previous)
            make.trailing.equalTo(contentView!)
            make.leading.equalTo(previous)
        }
    })

    previous = view
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is the scrollview not scrolling or are the views not layouted correctly?

Comment: after adding constraints, it does not scroll at all. Though content size is increased I checked in logs. if I try to follow same steps on storyboard it works file but applying same logic in code does not work. I am gonna have lots of views programmatically so really want to get it working. thanks